# Resultado 0 o null aparezca en la consulta

Tags: sql

Estoy creando una consulta en sql donde estoy trayendo los datos de mi almacén, solo que cuando la suma es 0 no me muestra el articulo en 0, se borra de la lista, y requiero que aparezca con cantidad 0

```
select A.Part_No,A.Name,A.Minimum_Inventory_Quantity,A.Maximum_Inventory_Quantity,SUM(B.Quantity),0 AS 'Inventario en almacen',
case when ISNULL(SUM(B.Quantity),0) < A.Minimum_Inventory_Quantity THEN 'El inventario esta fuera de minimo requerido'
     when ISNULL(SUM(B.Quantity),0) > A.Maximum_Inventory_Quantity THEN 'El inventario esta sobre el maximo permitido'
     END as 'Estado de Inventario'
from Part_v_Part A
INNER JOIN part_v_container B ON A.Part_Key = B.Part_Key
WHERE B.Active = 1 AND A.Part_Type = 'Raw Material' AND A.Part_Status = 'Activo'  AND B.Location <> 'Almacen Materia Prima en Produccion' AND B.Location LIKE 'ALMACEN%'
GROUP BY A.Part_Key,A.Part_No,A.Name,A.Part_Type,A.Part_Status,A.Part_Group_Key,A.Minimum_Inventory_Quantity,A.Maximum_Inventory_Quantity
ORDER BY A.Name
```

Comment: Prueba con un `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: no ya lo probé y no me regresa los datos si están en 0 los inventarios

Comment: Con un `LEFT JOIN part_v_container B ON A.Part_Key = B.Part_Key` siempre debería mostrarte todas las filas de `Part_v_Part`, si  hay alguna que no aparece el problema está en el `where`.

Comment: Lo unico que yo veo es que los datos si me aparecen cuando la suma no sale 0 si sale o no sale los datos que sumo

Comment: Cuando te refieres a los datos que no aparecen, estas hablando de una fila? por que no veo, si usas el `LEFT` con tu consulta, ninguna condición que haga que no aparezca una determinada fila. No hay un `HAVING` y no usarías el `INNER` que si te filtra datos de la tabla A cuando no los tienes en la tabla B

Comment: si la linea no sale pero es cuando el campo cantidad esta en 0

Comment: ¿Qué gestor de base de datos usas? Y, prueba tus consultas de forma simple, aplicando la condición y revisa los resultados, puede que los datos no estén como tú crees que están.